# What is the best way for creating asynchronous web application

Tags: ajax, web-applications, startup

i'm Trying to implement a web application and it's like a mix of some of twitter , facebook , pinterest features so the app is highly dependent on asynchronous calls to the server , any help with that i just want to know whether to use just ajax or there is some other magic do do better .

Answer (score 0):

you will need ajax to hit server side code. And will be in need soon when you need to call javascript from serveide code ie reverse ajax.

By using DWR framework you can acomplish both of them.

Other wise using jquery's ajax functionality will be a great help.